# Datediff and aggregate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL so please excuse my lack of knowledge.  This is the table i have based on the following statement:

```
    'select S_OPERATION.OPERATIONID, CHANGE_H.SERVICEREQNO, CHANGE_H.UPDATEDDATE
from sunrise.S_OPERATION inner join
CHANGE_H on S_OPERATION.OPERATIONID = CHANGE_H.OPERATIONID
where (S_OPERATION.OPERATIONID = 102005212) OR
                         (S_OPERATION.OPERATIONID = 102005218) or
                         (s_operation.operationid = 102005406) or
                         (s_operation.operationid = 102005401) or
                         (s_operation.operationid = 102005215)'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVCkN.jpg)

I would like to be able to calculate the time difference between events within the same job.

Please note: OperationID=event, Servicereqno=job

My end goal is to calculate the average time taken between each event and export this into a report, but i am having problems getting past the first hurdle.

I have tried the following statement however it does not work:

```
WITH cteOps AS 
(  
  SELECT 
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY change.servicereqid ORDER BY change.updateddate) seqid,
    updateddate, 
    servicereqid 
  FROM CHANGE.updateddate, CHANGE.addedby, S_OPERATION.operationid, CHANGE.servicereqid
)
SELECT 
  DATEDIFF(millisecond, o1.updateddate, o2.updateddate) updateddatediff, 
  servicereqid 
FROM cteOps o1 
JOIN cteOps o2 ON o1.seqid=o2.seqid+1 AND o1.servicereqid=o2.servicereqid;
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @AJ1791, Can you please provide sample data instead of image? so that we can help you.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but i am not sure what you mean by sample data

Comment: make your image result set as data, so that we will use that data and provide solution for you.

Comment: Thank you for your response, however unfortunately I still don't know what you mean, the above syntax provided that data.

Comment: The time difference between events? What does that mean? And how do you know when an event started and ended?

Comment: Really sorry I thought this was clear in the image.  The event is an operation (e.g. Logged) this is identified by the operationid field, the service req (job) is identified by the servicereqid field, the updateddate is when this operation was carried out.  I am looking to calculate the time difference between say the service being logged to the service pending authority (e.g. opid 102005212=logged, 102005215=pending authority)

Comment: Hi, just give us example, what kind of result you want from that image.

Comment: The result will have the following headers: OPERATIONID1, OPERATIONID2, SERVICEREQID, TIMETOTAL.  This is only way i can think, that would output the calculation between the events (opid)

Comment: What user3583912 means is that you should not link to an image, but write some sample data rows as text in your request, then write the result rows you'd expect for these sample rows.

Comment: And whenever something "does not work", tell us what doesn't work. Too many rows? Too few? No rows at all? Wrong values? A syntax error message?

Comment: when i ran the original statement, it was outputting the picture table only and not second part of the statement, the error message was:  Invalid object name CHANGE.UPDATEDDATE.  However this is a valid object?

Comment: The second query looks completely weird. `FROM CHANGE.updateddate, CHANGE.addedby, ...`??? With SQL we select data from *tables* (and views), but `CHANGE.updateddate` etc. are *columns*, aren't they?

Comment: And after your last edit your first query looks strange, too. Why do you cross join? This doesn't seem to make sense. Before there where operations/events related to services/jobs, now they are completely unrelated.

Comment: I have been changing this thing so much i have now got completely confused. I have now made a further change to the first syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Your two queries look quite different having different table names, etc. So you'd probably have to adjust my query below to match what you actually have.

You can look into the previous record with `LAG`. So a query showing all those events with a time difference to the previous one could be:

```
select 
    c.updateddate
  , c.addedby
  , so.operationid
  , c.servicereqid 
  , so.updateddate
  , datediff
    ( millisecond
    , lag(so.updateddate) over (partition by c.servicereqid order by so.updateddate)
    , so.updateddate
    ) as updateddatediff
from change c
inner join change_h ch 
  on c.servicereqid = ch.servicereqno 
  and ch.operationid in (102005212, 102005218, 102005406, 102005401, 102005215)
inner join s_operation so 
  on ch.operationid = so.operationid
order by 
  c.servicereqid,
  so.updateddate;
```

You can build up on this by using it as a derived table (a subquery in a FROM clause).

Comment: Apologies but can lag be used in Sql Server 2008?  I just noticed i did not tell you what version i was working on.  I have also updated the select table above to reflect changes made to the tables.

Comment: removed lag however i am getting the following error message Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'over'.